# What is the license of the OS X SDK?

Tags: macos, xcode, license

The Xcode package contains files that get installed in /System and /usr. Is it possible to redistribute those files in a different package? What kind of what are the legal implications?

Comment: [Mac SDK & Xcode Agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/xcode.pdf)

Comment: Downvoted. This solution would have been **very** easy to find using https://www.google.com

Comment: @ChrisMukherjee Finding the Xcode license is trivial, but the implications on what part of it make up an SDK are certainly unclear in the US where legal means a court has ruled on many competing laws and concepts and made a ruling. However a down vote for not showing research is totally justified or if you think it unuseful even if it's well documented. :-)

Comment: @bmike I think I just would have appreciated a comment to the effect of "I've found the Xcode license here: [link], but am unsure of what part of it are related to the SDK files..." just to show that some research had been conducted (if this was indeed the case)

Comment: I was unsure whether the SDK (the files I mentioned) and Xcode have the same license, since the SDK (or rather part of it) is available with the command line tools too, which is a set of open source utilities.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone You could either ask a more specific follow on question once you've digested the info here or edit your post to have more precise information on which specific package and which files you intend to repackage. Adding the details like in the comment below helps everyone answer and apply the thoughts here to their cases :-)

Answer (score 2):

The license for Xcode is pretty easy to find from:

- http://www.apple.com/legal/

Specifically, http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/xcode.pdf

Like the rest of Apple's licensed software, it states in part that licensees **may not rent, lease, lend, sell, sublicense or otherwise redistribute** the software. The only exceptions I've seen is derivative work that includes licensed components as part of the build process and not by simply repackaging parts or all of Apple's software.

The legal implications vary by your jurisdiction and whether you have signed any other agreements with Apple that would amend or override the standard license terms. Common sense says you would want to either ask Apple directly or get a lawyer to assist you before redistributing licensed and copyrighted goods.

Also, you might check at http://opensource.apple.com to see if portions of the code are open-sourced or have other licenses. Worst case, you'll need to arrange a license agreement with Apple on the use in your case if it's not per the standard license.

Comment: The Xcode Agreement does allow limited redistribution under specific conditions (as I read it, I could be misinterpreting): "You may make only as many internal use copies of the Developer Software as reasonably necessary to use the Developer Software as permitted under this License and distribute such copies only to your employees whose job duties require them to so use the Developer Software; provided that you reproduce on each copy of the Developer Software or portion thereof, all copyright or other proprietary notices contained on the original."

Comment: @njboot Seems like an edge case since the OP wants to put it in "another package" but they might be clear if it's an internal package only and explicitly for development team members?

Comment: The actual usage would be a publicly available archive to be installed along an open source compiler toolchain, for the means of providing a cross compile environment.